# PHP, Create dynamic list from files in a directory

Tags: php, list, variables, foreach, directory

I have a directory of files who's main purpose is to store php variables for inclusion into other files in the site. Each file contains the same set of variables, but with different values.

for example:

event1.php

```
<?php
  $eventActive = 'true';
  $eventName = My First Event;
  $eventDate = 01/15;
?>
```

event2.php

```
<?php
  $eventActive = 'true';
  $eventName = My Second Event;
  $eventDate = 02/15;
?>
```

In addition to calling these variables in other pages, I want to create a page that contains a dynamic list, based on the variables stored in each file within the directory.

Something like (basic concept):

```
for each file in directory ('/events') {
  if $eventActive = 'true'{ 
    <p><? echo $eventName ?></p>
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Event` class or an `array` of each event. Then populate it from the directory.

```
$index = 0;
foreach (array_filter(glob($dir.'/*'), 'is_file') as $file) {
  @include $file; // Parses the file, so the variables within are set.
  $events[$index]['active'] = $eventActive;
  $events[$index]['name'] = $eventName;
  $events[$index]['date'] = $evetnDate;
  $index++;
  // OR
  // $events[] = new Event($eventName, $eventDate, $eventActive);
}
// Now the $events array contains all your events.
// List out the active ones
foreach ($events as $event) {
  echo ($event['active'] === 'true') ? $event['name'] : '';
  // OR
  // echo $event->isActive() ? $event->getName() : '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How may i exclude specific files by name or type?

Comment: By name you could create an array of excluded names like `$exclude = ['file1.php', 'file2.php', ...];` and add an `if (in_array($file, $exclude) { // Skip it }`. As for *type* I'd have to look up how to determine a file's type in PHP. If you can use the file extension then know that `$file` is most likely `file_name.ext` so you can use one of the string manipulation functions to determine the extension and act on that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I spend some time with it and was able to reslove the issue with a cleaner solution, but utilizing an external json file to store the values

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('events.json');

    $jsonArray = json_decode($json, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array

    foreach ($jsonArray as $value) {

        if (($value['active'] === 't') && ($value['fromDate'] >= $currentDate)) {

            echo '<p>'.$value['title'].' '.$value['fromDate'].' - '.$value['toDate'].'</p>';
        }
    }

    echo $currentDate;  
?>
```